# How can you set up your gitlab-ci.yaml file to fetch data from private git repositories?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a gitlab repository with the following `gilab-ci.yaml` file:

```
---
image: ubuntu:22.04

stages:
  - before_script
  - test

before_script:
  - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

test:
  script:
    - git clone git@git.my-protected-repo.git
```

Which I created according to the [gitlab ci documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)

On a computer which is authenticated with an account that has permissions to this protected repostitory, I then fetched the private key by issuing:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 | clip.exe
```

and pasted it into my gitlab repository settings -> ci settings -> ci variables as following:

[image]

My key has the correct format and is recognized by `ssh-add` as a valid private key. However, in the CI log, I get the following error:

```
$ git clone git@git.my-protected-repo.git
Cloning into 'my-protected-repo'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:03
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is the rest of the commandline output before the git clone command:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.1 (f86890c6)
  on 1e2c33d179bc V95CvL9v, system ID: r_5FbOrrro7eMd
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:11
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:22.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:22.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:58db3edaf2be6e80f628796355b1bdeaf8bea1692b402f48b7e7b8d1ff100b02 for ubuntu:22.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:9a0bdde4188b896a372804be2384015e90e3f84906b750c1a53539b585fbbe7f ...
Preparing environment
00:04
Running on runner-v95cvl9v-project-43335424-concurrent-0 via 5211b24e8b01...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/1a2a3a4v/docker_runner_test/.git/
Checking out 3d997f5e as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:32
Using docker image sha256:58db3edaf2be6e80f628796355b1bdeaf8bea1692b402f48b7e7b8d1ff100b02 for ubuntu:22.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:9a0bdde4188b896a372804be2384015e90e3f84906b750c1a53539b585fbbe7f ...
$ command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5557 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [880 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [752 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [811 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1119 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [808 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1145 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [49.0 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [22.4 kB]
Fetched 25.9 MB in 2s (11.1 MB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbsd0 libcbor0.8 libedit2 libfido2-1 libmd0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 xauth
Suggested packages:
  keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbsd0 libcbor0.8 libedit2 libfido2-1 libmd0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client xauth
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 2103 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libmd0 amd64 1.0.4-1build1 [23.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.11.5-1 [44.8 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libcbor0.8 amd64 0.8.0-2ubuntu1 [24.6 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20210910-1build1 [96.8 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfido2-1 amd64 1.10.0-1 [82.8 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxau6 amd64 1:1.0.9-1build5 [7634 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxdmcp6 amd64 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5 [10.9 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.14-3ubuntu3 [49.0 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.7.5-1 [119 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.7.5-1 [666 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxext6 amd64 2:1.3.4-1build1 [31.8 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxmuu1 amd64 2:1.1.3-3 [10.2 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1 [908 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 xauth amd64 1:1.1-1build2 [27.5 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 2103 kB in 3s (809 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libmd0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4395 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libmd0_1.0.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmd0:amd64 (1.0.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbsd0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libbsd0_0.11.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbsd0:amd64 (0.11.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcbor0.8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libcbor0.8_0.8.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcbor0.8:amd64 (0.8.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libedit2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libedit2_3.1-20210910-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20210910-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfido2-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libfido2-1_1.10.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfido2-1:amd64 (1.10.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libxau6_1%3a1.0.9-1build5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1build5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libxcb1_1.14-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-data.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libx11-data_2%3a1.7.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-data (2:1.7.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libx11-6_2%3a1.7.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.7.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libxext6_2%3a1.3.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxmuu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libxmuu1_2%3a1.1.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssh-client.
Preparing to unpack .../12-openssh-client_1%3a8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-client (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xauth.
Preparing to unpack .../13-xauth_1%3a1.1-1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xauth (1:1.1-1build2) ...
Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1build5) ...
Setting up libcbor0.8:amd64 (0.8.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libx11-data (2:1.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libmd0:amd64 (1.0.4-1build1) ...
Setting up libfido2-1:amd64 (1.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.11.5-1) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20210910-1build1) ...
Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-3) ...
Setting up openssh-client (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ssh to provide /usr/bin/rsh (rsh) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rsh.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.gz (of link group rsh) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/slogin to provide /usr/bin/rlogin (rlogin) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rlogin.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/slogin.1.gz (of link group rlogin) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/scp to provide /usr/bin/rcp (rcp) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rcp.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/scp.1.gz (of link group rcp) doesn't exist
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.1-1build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 383
$ chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
$ ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
Identity added: /builds/1a2a3a4v/docker_runner_test.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY (my-email@a.com)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git-man less libbrotli1 libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl
  libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common
  libnghttp2-14 libperl5.34 libpsl5 librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db libssh-4 netbase openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.34
  publicsuffix
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-email git-gui
  gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn gdbm-l10n
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
  libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql ed
  diffutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libtap-harness-archive-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git git-man less libbrotli1 libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl
  libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common
  libnghttp2-14 libperl5.34 libpsl5 librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db libssh-4 netbase openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.34
  publicsuffix
0 upgraded, 26 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 76.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 perl-modules-5.34 all 5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1 [2976 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.23-1 [33.9 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.23-1 [6606 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libperl5.34 amd64 5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1 [4819 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 perl amd64 5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1 [232 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8 [1184 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1 [144 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 less amd64 590-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 [143 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2 [91.0 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 netbase all 6.3 [12.9 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.43.0-1build3 [76.3 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.21.0-1.2build2 [58.4 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 publicsuffix all 20211207.1025-1 [129 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.9-2build6 [315 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 [20.5 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 [53.8 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libldap-2.5-0 amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [183 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build4 [58.2 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.9.6-2build1 [184 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 [284 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1 [26.5 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8 [953 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8 [3141 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [15.9 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 [68.8 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 patch amd64 2.7.6-7build2 [109 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 15.3 MB in 4s (3897 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package perl-modules-5.34.
(Reading database ... 4771 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-perl-modules-5.34_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking perl-modules-5.34 (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgdbm6_1.23-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdbm6:amd64 (1.23-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm-compat4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgdbm-compat4_1.23-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.23-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libperl5.34:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libperl5.34_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libperl5.34:amd64 (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-perl_5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
Preparing to unpack .../05-openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
Preparing to unpack .../06-ca-certificates_20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package less.
Preparing to unpack .../07-less_590-1ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking less (590-1ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libexpat1_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netbase.
Preparing to unpack .../09-netbase_6.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking netbase (6.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnghttp2-14:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnghttp2-14_1.43.0-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpsl5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libpsl5_0.21.0-1.2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package publicsuffix.
Preparing to unpack .../12-publicsuffix_20211207.1025-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking publicsuffix (20211207.1025-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbrotli1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libbrotli1_1.0.9-2build6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2build6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules-db:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libsasl2-2_2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-2.5-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libldap-2.5-0_2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librtmp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssh-4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libssh-4_0.9.6-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.6-2build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libcurl3-gnutls_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../20-liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../21-git-man_1%3a2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../22-git_1%3a2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-common.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libldap-common_2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-common (2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libsasl2-modules_2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Preparing to unpack .../25-patch_2.7.6-7build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking patch (2.7.6-7build2) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2build2) ...
Setting up libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2build6) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1build3) ...
Setting up less (590-1ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up perl-modules-5.34 (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libldap-common (2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build4) ...
Setting up patch (2.7.6-7build2) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.6-2build1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up netbase (6.3) ...
Setting up openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up publicsuffix (20211207.1025-1) ...
Setting up libgdbm6:amd64 (1.23-1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
124 added, 0 removed; done.
Setting up libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.23-1) ...
Setting up libperl5.34:amd64 (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up perl (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

What other steps am I missing before I can access my gitlab repository via my gitlab runner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: "*Host key verification failed*" error is about **host key**, not user key. To fix: `ssh-keyscan git.my-protected-repo >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @phd I added the line `ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` after adding my private key with `ssh-add`, but I still get the same error. I also realized that my ~/.ssh folder is empty after the `ssh-add` command, could this be the reason why git clone is failing?

Comment: `ssh-add` doesn't put files to `~/.ssh/`, it adds a private key from a file to a running `ssh-agent` instance. Is there any output from `ssh-add`?

Comment: @phd it simply outputs `Identity added: /builds/<username>/docker_runner_test.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY (<email>)`

Comment: Then `ssh-add` worked as designed, the key was added to the agent.

Comment: The error is from the command `git clone git@git.my-protected-repo.git` but you use `ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 gitlab.com`. Is `git.my-protected-repo` at `gitlab.com`?